# OAuth2 login with Nativescript - Avoiding external browser / webview is possible?

Tags: spring-boot, nativescript, jhipster, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a new project with OpenId Connect based security. Being a novice with this technology (and with mobile development too), I wasn't able to find an exact answer to my question.

Little introduction to the project:

- Generated the API module / entity administration app with jHipster (Spring boot, Keycloak as Identity provider, and PostgreSql for DB).
- Generated the mobile app with Nativescript-Angular
- Installed Nativescript-OAuth2 plugin

The client (NS app) is the part I'm working on now.

Before giving up and switch to something simpler, I'd like to ask if using a login form inside the app, without opening an external web browser to insert credentials, it's approved by the official OAuth2-OIdC specification.

My concern is that I've read in the Nativescript-OAuth2 plugin board, [here](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/issues/91) that Apple is not accepting external redirections like the one mentioned above.

To be honest, I agree with that, the user experience could be affected by this view switching, and become confused.

The idea of a normal login form, seems possible and already done, as you can see in [this](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/10/10/react-native-spring-boot-mobile-app) article. 
We're talking about a jhipster project, this time integrated with React Native. 
The authentication happens entirely in the app, without any external browser help, so it's possible.

Personally I've read that OAuth2 specification tells explicitly to use the external browser, but maybe my interpretation is not correct.

The purpose of this question is to clarify if is possible to follow the OAuth2 / OpenId Connect standard, by means of "simple" HTTP requests, without any external browser or WebView?

I know that the OAuth2 / OIDC Standard websites are reporting any kind of information. It's true that at first glance, coming from web development, or simpler security methods, it's a bit hard to know which way to follow. Things are even more complicated when you are using NativeScript, as it's an Angular app transpiled to native Android - iOS code.

I take the view that this question needs to be addressed as this security protocol is becoming the standard now, and the same is for frameworks like NativeScript, React Native, AppCellerator Titanium, etc.

**Note:** On NS website there's a document telling you that it's easy to implement OAuth2 login with featured Kinvey's extensions. The problem is that when you have finished to configure your environment, and start following that doc, then you discover that Kinvey services are not free any more.

Comment: The plugin already implements Safari View Controller APIs to provide in app login experience. You have to set `openIdSupport` params to `"oid-full"` in your provider configuration. Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.. I missed that part in the readme. Btw I've tried with ```oid-full``` and it switches to another view.
With postman I've obtained the access token with success, just with a single POST.
I will try with ```TnsOaUnsafeProviderOptions``` to configure my custom provider to see if I can replicate the same behavior on my app.
The actual configuration is not that bad, I think that I will try to use it in case every other attempt fails. 
I'm really scared about Apple refusing the app submission, that would lead to switch all the security layer... a total pain.

Comment: Ever tried https://appauth.io/ ? "Native App SDK for OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect implementing modern best practices".

Comment: I haven't but you could if you want, all the APIs will be accessible within your project once you add the POD / Gradle libraries in your project.

Comment: JHipster committer here, and author of the blog post you mentioned. The React Native library for JHipster -- Ignite JHipster -- is using https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth. This leverages the aforementioned appauth.io. I'm the author of Ionic for JHipster, which also uses AppAuth. The last time I tried to get NativeScript working with OAuth, I was unable to, so it's encouraging to hear you have it working!

Comment: Hi Matt, glad you read the post, I was really tempted to follow your tutorial, but I'm coming from VueJS, and after years I've finally started a project with Ng, It would be bad to leave it just for this problem. I was near to cry when it worked :D ... It's definetely not easy. 
It would be nice to have a form like you did, but the webview solution is not that bad, also it has the social login stuff already configured.
Maybe appauth.io is more configurable, I would give it a try but I'm out of time now.
I've mixed the docs with code examples on github. I can share the configuration, np!

Comment: Thanks Manoj, this is nice to know too. Are you using nativescript since a while?

Comment: The reason that an external browser is preferable is because it gives the user an added sense of security. They are directed to a login page that they recognize (gmail, for example) in an app they recognize (Safari, for example). They verify their credentials with the external service, and that service passes an auth token back to the app. The user doesn't need to be worried about a MITM attack where you scoop their login credentials.

Comment: Hi @halfer, I've edited the question in order to make it less "opinion-based". I don't want to seem the one who blame others, but the original title was changed from another user, who removed words like "Nativescript". 
This question is directed to nativescript developers (and other similar frameworks). There is no article, tutorial or discussion treating the argument well. This can be a good starting point to find a best practice, and maybe write an article in future. 
I've edited the title and body, is possible to reopen it? thx

Comment: @IanMacDonald, that's true when using external Identity providers, but when the user registers directly on the app, you can manage everything inside your app. 
As stated in previous comments, a Webview is not that bad.
But just to know, I would like to clarify whether the internal form is a valid approach, or it goes against the specifications

Comment: Hi Funder. I can't see the edit you are referring to in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60657568/revisions), perhaps because the original title did not mention NativeScript. But no matter: I do think the question is better now. I have made some more edits, as there were two items that still made it off-topic: (1) references to discussions, and (2) requests for tutorials. I have cast a reopen vote (you need two more).

Comment: Hi @halfer, you're right, NativeScript wasn't in the title, I thought rev.#2 "no tags in title" removed it. Never mind, thanks for reopening, and for editing as well. I'm not english mother tongue..still learning :-) I've found your guide though (how to use SO), I will read it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible using [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3)

```
 +----------+
 | Resource |
 |  Owner   |
 |          |
 +----------+
      v
      |    Resource Owner
     (A) Password Credentials
      |
      v
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
 |         |>--(B)---- Resource Owner ------->|               |
 |         |         Password Credentials     | Authorization |
 | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
 |         |<--(C)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
 |         |    (w/ Optional Refresh Token)   |               |
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
```

Note, that Resource Owner is the User and Client is the Application.

This login-type usually has to be turned on. By many Identity Providers such as Keycloak this option is called `Direct Access Grants` and might be turned on in the settings of the client.

Comment: Hi Dennis, so if I understood the point, we are talking about the Password Credentials flow (username + password) - Isn't it the less secure method of oAuth2? 
I was thinking about that, if I have to use credentials, then why use such complicated auth protocol? (I'm not working with oAuth2 since a lot, maybe I'm confusing it with the implicit flow)

Comment: Hi @funder7, It is indeed less secure than logging in using a browser page of the identity provider, but if you want to avoid using a browser page and login using the login and the password, then it's a way to do that.